# How do I more easily copy and paste all the content in open file on remote server over ssh using tmux and iterm2?

Tags: macos, vim, copy-paste, tmux, iterm2

**Problem:** I'm on a mac running a tmux server. Within my local tmux session, I connect to a remote linux server and open a file with vim. The text I want does not fit in a single pane without having to scroll. I want to grab the text in the file and copy and paste all of it to my local machine's memory.

**Current Solution:**

My current procedure for copying and pasting is very convoluted:

1. Zoom on the pane with `ctl-b z`
2. Turn off numbering in vim with `:set nonumber`
3. If the file or text I want does not fit in entire pane, I hit `cmd -` until the text is small enough to fit in the entire pane
4. Select text I need with my mouse while holding down the `option` key.
5. Hit `cmd-c` to copy to my local machine.

**Better Solution?**

My current solution is tedious and I'm tired of wondering if there is a better way. Anyone got a better solution?

Ideally, I'd love to be able to select the text with vim and have iterm2 somehow detect what has been selected in a pane and run a single keystroke to copy to my local machine. Not sure if that's possible or not.

Comment: Just found this: https://github.com/wincent/clipper Looks like it is exactly what I need. Anyone try it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I went with the solution at [github.com/wincent/clipper](http://github.com/wincent/clipper) which works on my mac running macos 11.2.3.

The install instructions seem to be a little dated and are a bit confusing if you don't read them carefully. It took some trial and error to figure out how to get this working with vim on the remote machine:

1. Install with brew on your mac
2. Launch clipper as a daemon with `brew services start clipper`
3. On the remote machine, add the following line to your vimrc file:

`nnoremap <leader>y :call system('nc -q 1 localhost 8377', @0)<CR>`

Note: I had to add the `-q 1` in there because I found vim would hang otherwise. The `-q 1` arguments are not in the official documentation.

4. In your mac's `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *
     RemoteForward 8377 localhost:8377
```

5. Make sure your remote server has port 8377 open!
6. On the remote machine, open a file with vim. Yank some lines. Then hit `<leader>y`.

Note: It took a while before it finally dawned on me that just `<leader>y` doesnt' work by itself. It's a two-step vim command process: 1) yank the text with a vim command 2) send the copied text to your mac with `<leader>y`.

That's it. My life feels so much better now. :)